# Почему в цикле добавляется только последний элемент списка?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for

Мне нужно перебрать таблицы, которые хранятся в списке `dictinary` и года, которые хранятся в списке `dictinary_year`. Проблема в том, что в результате в каждую таблицу добавляется последнее значение из списка.

```
dictinary = [data,data_2,data_3]
dictinary = ["2014_3","2014_4","2021_3"]
for i in range(len(dictinary)):
    for n in range(len(dictinary_year)):
        dictinary[i].loc[:,"year"] = dictinary_year[n]
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста примеры данных, которые вы храните в переменных data, data_2 и т.д  и опишите результат, который хотите получить. Наверняка в Pandas можно обойтись и без циклов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хочу дополнить уже имеющиеся ответы. Не используйте циклы вида `for i in range(len(collection))`, если всё, для чего вам нужна переменная `i` - это получить доступ к элементу `collection[i]`. Есть же простой и понятный цикл, перебирающий элементы коллекции: `for item in collection`. Так и короче, и понятнее, и в индексах не запутаетесь, особенно если циклы вложенные и индексов много. А для одновременного перебора нескольких коллекций одинаковой длины есть функция `zip`.

Применительно к вашему случаю, правда, не могу точный код написать, потому что не совсем понятно, что вы делаете. Но предположу, что планировалось что-то такое:

```
dictinary = [data,data_2,data_3]
dictinary_year = ["2014_3","2014_4","2021_3"]
for dic,year in zip(dictinary, dictinary_year):
    dic["year"] = year
```

Answer (score 2):

> Почему в цикле добавляется только последний элемент списка?

Потому, что вы делаете присваивание одного элемента **всему** столбцу. Т.е. одно и то же значение будет присвоено всем элементам столбца. Соответственно в столбце `"year"` в каждом фрейме окажется последнее значение из `dictinary_year`.

Кроме этого Numpy и Pandas придумали для того, чтобы облегчить у ускорить работу с матрицами и табличными данными. Сделано это за счет введения быстрых векторизированных функций, которые позволяют оперировать сразу векторами и матрицами, вместо медленной поэлементной обработки в циклах.
Воспользуйтесь этой мощью:

```
for i in range(len(dictinary)):
    dictinary[i]["year"] = dictinary_year[i]
```

PS вы не объяснили что вы хотите сделать/получить, поэтому нам приходится гадать по вашему *нерабочему* коду. Это очень неэффективно. Прочтите пожалуйста [как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/) и следуйте в будущих вопросах рекомендациям из этого FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Вы два раза выполняете присваивание переменной *dictinary*:

```
dictinary = [data,data_2,data_3]
dictinary = ["2014_3","2014_4","2021_3"]
```

и ни разу - переменной *dictinary_year*